# Android textview usage as label and value

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to group two textviews in a group and use like a label and value. Is there any component to group two textviews in android? How can it be accomplished in android layout?

[image: Sample label value]

Comment: You mean beyond just placing them in the same layout? Why do you need them "grouped"?

Comment: No.There is'nt. From what i'm seeing you could use a Table Layout to implement that.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `<LinearLayout>` to group elements horizontaly. Also you should use style to set margins, background and other properties. This will allow you not to repeat code for every label you use.
Here is an example:

```
<LinearLayout
                    style="@style/FormItem"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                        style="@style/FormLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_element_height"
                        android:text="@string/name_label"
                        />

                <EditText
                        style="@style/FormText.Editable"
                        android:id="@+id/cardholderName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_element_height"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:hint="@string/card_name_hint"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Also you can create a custom view base on the layout above. 
Have you looked at [Creating custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a Custom List View, such that you define a Layout once and draw it for every row in the list view.