# How can i display Bundle data to textview one by one?

Tags: android, bundle

How can i display Bundle data to text view one by one?

I have a activity who have 10 number of text view.I want display all bundle data to text view.

This is the bundle format.

```
Bundle[{INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail, CHANNEL_ID=WAP, CHECKSUMHASH=IIUBjkuTPs9xx/TnzKbR0BkWKvsumSCMyrYBIZzAppNTdJGC+U+XyjESvFwCax/ME2dexR05YKDJuZSsgpSxxDtAUb6bGeOs9u/1t9FxxkE=, MOBILE_NO=7428453915, REQUEST_TYPE=DEFAULT, TXN_AMOUNT=4.0, MID=klbGlV59135347348753, EMAIL=singhamit1632@gmail.com, THEME=merchant, payt_STATUS=1, CUST_ID=48, WEBSITE=paytm, ORDER_ID=FCF449}]
```

first activity who have bundle data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentPageActvity.this,CancelPaymentActivity.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("ss", inResponse.toString());

intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

second activity who fetched data and display on textview

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

Bundle b = CancelPaymentActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
String v = b.getString("ss").toString();
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID.setText(v);
```

INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID==text-view name

Comment: Please show what you've attempted already.

Comment: @tavnab did u understand my problem?

Comment: I understand the problem, but there still isn't enough information to solve it. You have provided your sample code, but exactly what part is not working? Are you having trouble adding _any_ text to your TextView, or just the text in your bundle? Have you logged the value in your `v` variable to make sure you're getting back the value you assigned in the 1st activity? If you can get pass a string from one activity to another via an `Intent`, and you can put an arbitrary string in a `TextView`, your problem is mostly solved; let us know which of these aren't working so we can help.

Comment: Here are some answers to help you with the components you need to build a full solution: [Adding text to a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374117/how-to-create-simple-android-textview-and-display-text-on-it-using-java-code), [Passing info between activities using Intents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607992/android-java-pass-values-through-intents-bundles-or-parcelables)

Comment: @tavnab I fetched bundle value into second activity but i have a problem to display bundle data to textview like  .......INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail   it is my first textview .....my second textview like  CHANNEL_ID=WAP.I need this type of format

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a `Bundle` of values and a `layout` (e.g. a `ListLayout`) in your activity, to which you want to add a `TextView` for some or all entries in your bundle.

If your layout is static, your `TextView`s are already defined, and you know which bundle values go in which `TextView`, you can do this:

```
TextView industryType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textIndustryType);
industryType.setText(bundle.getString("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"));
// ...
```

Or define a map relating bundle key to text view ID and use that. For example:

```
private static Map<String, String> keyToTextViewId = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    keyToTextViewId.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", R.id.textIndustryType);
    keyToTextViewId.put("CHANNEL_ID", R.id.textChannelId);
    // ...
}

private TextView getTextViewFor(String bundleKey) {
    String textViewId = keyToTextViewId.get(bundleKey);
    return (textViewId != null ? findViewById(textViewId) : null);
}

private void updateTextViews(Bundle bundle) {
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        TextView tv = getTextViewFor(key);
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.setText(bundle.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
}

// ...

    Bundle bundle = CancelPaymentActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
    updateTextViews(bundle);
```

If your layout is not static (i.e. you don't know what bundles you're getting and need to create your TextViews at runtime), then it's similar to the above, except you need to create your TextViews & also call `layout.addView(TextView)` as you go:

```
// Once the TextViews are created, access them through this map
private Map<String, TextView> keyToTextView = new HashMap<String, TextView>();

// Helper function to create consistent TextViews, creating & adding a new
// one if needed
private TextView getTextViewFor(String bundleKey, Layout layout) {
    TextView tv = keyToTextView.get(bundleKey);
    if (tv != null) {
        return tv;
    } else {
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(/* updated as needed */));
        keyToTextView.put(key, tv);
        layout.addView(tv);
        return tv;
    }
}

// ...

private void updateTextViews(Bundle bundle, Layout layout) {
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        getTextViewFor(key, layout).setText(bundle.get(key).toString());
    }
}
```

In the latter case, you probably want additional code to filter for which keys to actually display, and in what order. You'll probably also want to define labels for each TextView, where the label contains the bundle key (or some user-friendly version thereof). You can find details on how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583655/3149036).